# NLP - Removing Stop Words and Counting Word Frequency

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp, stop-words

I currently have a working script to do a simple count of word frequency across a column **(conversation_message__body)** of data coming from our database. A sample of the working code and the output (image) is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = df.conversation_message__body.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()

y = pd.DataFrame(data=x)

y.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True)

print(y)
```

The issue is that there are many words I want to exclude from this analysis. This is a common issue in NLP as I understand. So I altered my script as seen below:

```
# Import stopwords with nltk.
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

stop = stopwords.words('english')
newStopWords = ['hello','hi','hey','im','get']
stop.extend(newStopWords)

df['conversation_message__body'] = df.conversation_message__body.str.replace("[^\w\s]", "").str.lower()

df['conversation_message__body'] = df['conversation_message__body'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x.split() if item not in stop])

x = df.conversation_message__body.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()

y = pd.DataFrame(data=x)

y.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True)

print(y)
```

This is **NOT** working for me and returns no results. Even when I try `print(x)` to see what the initial transformation looks like, I only get back > `Series([], dtype: int64)`

I am pretty sure there are some basics I am missing here, but I have been working on this for a while with no luck. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] ?

Comment: Im guessing thats difficult because I cant provide the input here. The input is 1 column and many rows, which each cell being a long form text field encompassing conversation notes.

I obviously dont understand MREs as much as I should, but that second code block is what I am trying to get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `str` in your column, not list of words.

Small example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'conv': 
                   ["hi im Jon. I am reaching out to schedule a meeting on Monday.", "That wouldn't be possible as I am out."]})
```

Data looks like:

```
    conv
0   jon reaching schedule meeting monday
1   wouldnt possible
```

Then:

```
df['conv'] = df['conv'].str.replace("[^\w\s]", "").str.lower()
```

Now you need to have string in `conv`, your code gives list of strings.

```
df['conv'] = df['conv'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in stop]))
df['conv'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
wouldnt     1
jon         1
possible    1
meeting     1
reaching    1
monday      1
schedule    1
dtype: int64
```